# Adding user to private text channel - discordjs

Tags: discord

I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing in terms of permissions to add a user to a text channel that is private via http. The user is already in the guild/server and if I were to update the bot permissions to administrator then it works, but if I use the select permissions I have set for example

[image]

I get

```
Error adding user to guild or assigning role: Error: HTTP error!
 Status: 403 - {"message": "Missing Access", "code": 50001}
    at discordFetch
```

If I were to select every single permission except Administrator like this
[image]

Then I get `Error: HTTP error! Status: 403 - {"message": "Missing Access", "code": 50001}`

still. I'm trying not to use Administrator but only permissions needed, but if selecting every single permission doesn't work but choosing administrator does add user to private text channel once they are already in guild then what am I missing? Also I have the bot role at the very top when you go to discord Server Settings > Roles. I read it needs to be above other roles to assign permissions.

Does it have to do with this being wrong somehow?

```js
const permissions = {
    allow: "1024",
    deny: "0",
    type: "1",
  };
```

Here's how I add users to private channel which again works as Administrator.

```js
export async function addUserToPrivateChannel(
  channelId: string,
  userId: string
) {
  const url = `${discordBaseUrl}/channels/${channelId}/permissions/${userId}`;
  const permissions = {
    allow: "1024",
    deny: "0",
    type: "1",
  };

  const options = {
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bot ${DISCORD_TOKEN}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(permissions),
  };

  return await discordFetch(url, options);
}


async function discordFetch(url, options) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, options);

    // Log rate limit information
    const rateLimit = response.headers.get("X-RateLimit-Limit");
    const rateLimitRemaining = response.headers.get("X-RateLimit-Remaining");
    const rateLimitReset = response.headers.get("X-RateLimit-Reset");

    if (rateLimitReset) {
      const rateLimitResetDate = new Date(Number(rateLimitReset) * 1000);
      console.log(
        `Rate Limit Reset: ${rateLimitResetDate.toLocaleTimeString()}`
      );
    }
    console.log(`Rate Limit: ${rateLimit}`);
    console.log(`Rate Limit Remaining: ${rateLimitRemaining}`);

    if (!response.ok) {
      const text = await response.text();
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status} - ${text}`);
    }

    if (response.status === 204 || response.status === 201) {
      console.log(
        `User added successfully with status code: ${response.status}`
      );
      return { status: response.status }; 
    } else {
      return await response.json();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error with Discord fetch:", error);
    throw error; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've hit one of the edge cases with Discord's permission system where something isn't properly covered by the standard permission values; the good news is that there *is* another option available to you!

That is to manage access to the channel through roles, this is also the recommended way of managing channel access. So you'd have to edit the bot to have a configurable role for channel access that it can (un)assign from users instead of shoving the user object into the channel permission overrides.

If the bot is meant for private use in a server (or a small selection of them) then it's more than fine to hard-code or manually map channel IDs to roles. In any other case, you'd want a table that lays out `server | channel | role` access combinations.

---

Addition after some stuff in the comments:

On the other hand, if you find yourself in a situation where your **really** need to specifically support adding single users to a channel, you're stuck with asking for admin permissions. As an alternative, you could also look into leveraging private threads in that case, but I don't know if and how well discord.js supports that feature.

Comment: This is one way, but also not the best. After you have say even 20 private channels where you want to add users, this would add up, creating a new role for each new channel. This would clutter the role hierarchy in discord and make role management (from the server admins' side) a nightmare.

So just asking for administrator is by far easier(for both the dev and server admin).

Comment: If you have that many private channels with unique combinations of users, then you're not in scope of an average server and I... kinda wonder why you'd want to automate that kinda nightmare

Comment: one reason can be a tickets bot. So when a user clicks a create ticket btn for example, a new channel will be created which will have a few roles and the ticket creator with read/write access. That might be the reason they are making this bot and this is the approach that many popular ticket bots(ex - [TicketsBot](https://ticketsbot.net)) take.

Comment: In my use case I have an app that integrates with a bunch of user servers where they will have their own channels with some that are private. I'm using oauth to get the channels and then dynamically trying to add users to private channels within these servers so if I understand you correctly and correct me if I'm wrong, but you're saying I need to create a role and add channel access to that role? If so then what about the role that gets added automatically when a user authorizes my app in their discord. Can I use that role and assign permissions to it? I might be misunderstanding you though

Comment: No, I was referring to the general case of ways to add users to channels. In the case of TicketsBot I have no idea what that does; with other support system bots the DMs between bots and users is usually used to proxy messages back and forth, or admin perms are requested.
If you have a use case where you **really** need to add specific users to channels and nobody else, you're stuck to admin perms unless you can leverage private threads for your purposes

Comment: @RivenSkaye, TicketsBot will create a new channel in the server where the interaction was run and that channel can only be viewed by the ticket support staff(who have the **Tickets Support** role) and admins(who have the **Tickets Admin** role). I believe you are referring to the [ModMail Bot](https://modmail.xyz), correct? 

From this, I believe OP can make the best decision.

Comment: I think I realize what you meant now in your original answer. A private channel needs the server admin to assign the member role to it manually. This part can't be automated I don't think. I was trying to add the role of the bot to the channel so it would have permission to add users to a channel, but I realize now this isn't how it works. The bot can't add the bot role to private channel or add users directly to a private channel without admin access. It needs to add the member role to member. That member role needs to be added manually to private channel by server owner though for it work.

Comment: For roles it's not an issue if the bot role has permission to manage the channel; it's specifically for single user overrides that it requires admin permissions. But yes, to achieve what you want with arbitrary amounts of users and channels, there's no clean way.
Bots like ModMail circumvent this by proxying messages between bot DMs and a ticket channel. That's also a possibility worth exploring I suppose

Answer (score 0):

A bot will need the **Administrator** permission to manage access to a channel. So there is no other way than to ask for the **Administrator** permission when inviting.

Comment: I'm not totally sure that's right. You could be right, but generally in software development there is the principle of least privilege so it's hard for me to think that administrator permission is what discord recommends. Again, you could be right, but that wouldn't be common practice.

Comment: @user6680, I understand, even I was surprised when I saw this but it just seems to be the only solution that I have found. You can demonstrate this by creating a server, making a new role in it, giving the role every permission other than administrator and viewing the server with that role(using the 3 dots that when clicked give the view server as role btn). You can see that it will not allow you to add users to a text channel.

Reply here if you have any more questions :)